# Emails delivered to Microsoft/Outlook successfully, but do not arrive in inbox/spam folders

Tags: postfix, smtp

Struggling with this for awhile.  Have searched everywhere, read every post/thread I can find and have a thread started on Microsoft's "Answers" site, but the replies there are so slow.

I am running Plesk w/ PostFix and emails are being successfully sent to Microsoft servers, however the emails never arrive in the Inbox (or Junk folder, or anywhere else) but also do not bounce.  They are simply silently dropped somewhere.

I have SPF, DomainKeys and DomainKey Signing all working properly:

**Response from Port 25:**

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   pass
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham
```

**Line from maillog:**

```
Aug 27 14:49:15 server postfix/smtp[5303]: DEC011C2013: to=<mypersonalemail@outlook.com>, relay=mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.21/0.02/0.98/0.57, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250  <53FE525B.1050602@eaglehomes.ca> Queued mail for delivery)
```

**MX Toolbox Diagnostic Results**

```
220 server.eaglehomes.ca ESMTP Postfix

SMTP Banner Check   OK - 209.97.210.84 resolves to server.eaglehomes.ca
SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch   OK - Reverse DNS matches SMTP Banner
SMTP TLS    OK - Supports TLS.
SMTP Connection Time    0.811 seconds - Good on Connection time
SMTP Open Relay OK - Not an open relay.
SMTP Transaction Time   3.167 seconds - Good on Transaction Time
```

**main.cf**

```
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.17/README_FILES
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
disable_vrfy_command = yes
mynetworks = , 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailbox_size_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
myhostname = server.eaglehomes.ca
message_size_limit = 51200000
non_smtpd_milters =

# OpenDKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768, inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters =
```

Email functions fine otherwise - the server does hundreds, if not thousands of emails per day and has no issues sending to/from any other service.

I'm at a loss as to what to check/try next and would love some help.

Comment: Really?  A downvote with no comments or suggestions?

Comment: Do you receive mails if you send to another account on your same server? What about sending to a non microsoft account? what's your postfix configuration? Is the postfix queue empty?

Comment: I've updated the question with main.cf file.  Send email to/from a non-microsoft account works fine (the server handles hundreds, sometimes thousands of emails per day).  The queue is empty.

Comment: Hi Luke, sorry for the late reply. I checked your DNS and DKIM records and all seems fair. I had quite a lot of trouble in the past with MS servers for what ended up being my dkim key not long enough, but yours is 1024bit already. Maybe you can ask to Microsoft, like @mfinni suggests? Keep us updated.

Comment: Thanks for double checking the settings.  I figured they were correct too.  I have finally heard back from Microsoft and they were able to make some changes on their end that helped, but didn't specify what.

Comment: I'd bet your mails were all caught by some weird rule in their spam filter.. well, good to know that they answered and even solved the problem! Honestly, I've never had a good experience with MS's support, maybe they're getting better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run get-messagetracking on the Exchange server. Or have the admin of that system do it, if you can't. If it's Microsoft, open a ticket with them.

SMTP 250 is a success code, so something in their system is dropping the ball, from your perspective. There's literally nothing you can do about it, from a technical perspective, if you don't manage the system that gave a 250 to your sendmail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That is what I figured as well and did finally hear back from Microsoft.  They made a change that corrected the issue, but won't tell me what it was.  Strange.

Comment: I suspect that they use a whitelist.  If you run your own mailserver, it would then be blocked by default.

Comment: A link to the appropriate microsoft help desk would really improve this answer.

Comment: @Keith - I'm not sure what you mean. Are you suggesting that I should have included instructions on how to open a ticket with Microsoft for mail delivery issues to outlook.com? I'm sure that's changed since 2014, so it probably wouldn't improve the answer much.

Comment: That's true.  I figure they have several help desks and I want to post my ticket in the right place.  I did find a [digital ocean forum thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/website-email-arrives-at-gmail-and-other-domains-but-not-hotmail-com-or-outlook-com) with some promising links at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps [here](https://skrilnetz.net/?page_id=1112) to make it work.

- Setup a SPF record
- Setup DKIM
- Setup a DMARC record
- Setup a reverse DNS record
- HELO must be a host name not an IP
- Make sure that your IP is not on a blacklist
- Use a static IP address for your server
- Sign up for JMRP and SNDS